# Foundation iframe disappears when reveal modal

Tags: php, html

When I click on a button to reveal a modal and then to make it disappear the flex-video iframes from that page disappears too , how can I fix this? (after  I open the modal also the iframe reappears and when I close it..the iframe does the same thing )

The modal reveal button and modal content :

```
<a data-reveal-id="LoginModal" href="#" class="button">Login</a>
    <div  id="LoginModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Login Form</h2>
    <?php

    // show negative messages
    if ($login->errors) {
        foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;    
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">

    <label for="login_input_username">Username</label>
    <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_name" required />

    <label for="login_input_password">Password</label>
    <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />

    <input type="submit"  name="login" value="Log in" />

    </form>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

And the flex-video

```
 <div class="flex-video">
    <iframe width="238" height="210" src="<?php echo $i["post_video1"];?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

The site link for the live example http://world-debate.net/index.php ( you can check with the login / register button on the top right corner )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is class "flex-video". When I remove it, the frame stay on right place. Try to change class name to another or check attributes here.